AWS RDS MySQL - Error Code: 1419. You do not have SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled by default
I'm getting this error event when setting "log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1" in the AWS RDS console. I'm using workbench and I need to create several Triggers. Here is the script and trying to execute unsuccessfully:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `yume-preview`.`aikon_articulo_AFTER_INSERT`;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `yume-preview`.`aikon_articulo_AFTER_UPDATE`;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `yume-preview`.`aikon_marca_AFTER_INSERT`;

/* Artículos */
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `yume-preview`.`aikon_articulo_AFTER_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT
ON aikon_articulo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO articulo_precio(aik_ar_codigo, arp_utilidad_web)
    VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_ap_utilidad);
    
    -- INSERT INTO articulo_web(aik_ar_codigo, ar_descripcion_web)
    -- VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_ar_descri);
    
    -- Primer row en cada tabla de historiales.
    INSERT INTO aikon_articulo_historial_costo_neto(aik_ar_codigo, aik_ar_cosnet)
    VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_ar_cosnet);
    INSERT INTO aikon_articulo_historial_stock_total(aik_ar_codigo, aik_stock_total)
    VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_stock_total);
    INSERT INTO aikon_articulo_historial_utilidad(aik_ar_codigo, aik_ap_utilidad)
    VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_ap_utilidad);
    
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `yume-preview`.`aikon_articulo_AFTER_UPDATE`
AFTER UPDATE
ON aikon_articulo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /* Tablas Historiales */
    IF(OLD.aik_ar_cosnet != NEW.aik_ar_cosnet) THEN
        -- Le pongo fechaFin al último row (el que no tiene fecha_hora_hasta)
        UPDATE aikon_articulo_historial_costo_neto 
        SET fecha_hora_hasta = NOW() 
        WHERE fecha_hora_hasta IS NULL;
        
        INSERT INTO aikon_articulo_historial_costo_neto(aik_ar_codigo, aik_ar_cosnet)
        VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_ar_cosnet);
    END IF;
    
    IF(OLD.aik_stock_total != NEW.aik_stock_total) THEN
        -- Le pongo fechaFin al último row (el que no tiene fecha_hora_hasta)
        UPDATE aikon_articulo_historial_stock_total 
        SET fecha_hora_hasta = NOW() 
        WHERE fecha_hora_hasta IS NULL;
        
        INSERT INTO aikon_articulo_historial_stock_total(aik_ar_codigo, aik_stock_total)
        VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_stock_total);
    END IF;
    
    IF(OLD.aik_ap_utilidad != NEW.aik_ap_utilidad) THEN
        -- Le pongo fechaFin al último row (el que no tiene fecha_hora_hasta)
        UPDATE aikon_articulo_historial_utilidad 
        SET fecha_hora_hasta = NOW() 
        WHERE fecha_hora_hasta IS NULL;
        
        INSERT INTO aikon_articulo_historial_utilidad(aik_ar_codigo, aik_ap_utilidad)
        VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.aik_ap_utilidad);
    END IF;
    /* Fin Tablas Historiales */
    
    /* Publicarweb ultíma fecha modificado TODO: VER */
    IF (OLD.aik_ar_publicarweb != NEW.aik_ar_publicarweb) THEN
        UPDATE articulo_web
        SET ar_publicarweb_ultima_fecha_modificado = NOW()
        WHERE aik_ar_codigo = OLD.aik_ar_codigo;
    END IF;
    
    /* ESA_CODIGO ultíma fecha modificado TODO: VER */
    IF(OLD.aik_esa_codigo != NEW.aik_esa_codigo) THEN
        UPDATE articulo_web
        SET ar_esa_codigo_ultima_fecha_modificado = NOW()
        WHERE aik_ar_codigo = OLD.aik_ar_codigo;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `yume-preview`.`articulo_precio_AFTER_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT
ON articulo_precio FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO articulo_precio_historial_arp_utilidad_web(aik_ar_codigo, arp_utilidad_web)
    VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.arp_utilidad_web);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `yume-preview`.`articulo_precio_AFTER_UPDATE`
AFTER UPDATE
ON articulo_precio FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(OLD.arp_utilidad_web != NEW.arp_utilidad_web) THEN
        UPDATE articulo_precio_historial_arp_utilidad_web 
        SET fecha_hora_hasta = NOW() 
        WHERE fecha_hora_hasta IS NULL;
        
        INSERT INTO articulo_precio_historial_arp_utilidad_web(aik_ar_codigo, arp_utilidad_web)
        VALUES(NEW.aik_ar_codigo, NEW.arp_utilidad_web);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
/* FIN Articulos */

/* MARCAS */
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `yume-preview`.`aikon_marca_AFTER_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT
ON aikon_marca FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO marca_extension(aik_ma_codigo)
    VALUES(NEW.aik_ma_codigo);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

Also, if I run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin_trust_function_creators'; from workbench, I get the value OFF.
Any idea why is this not working?
